# QML global access to C++ class

Tags: c++, qt, qml

My app has 3 level: 
 - Main Form
 - Settings
 - Device searching

From the main form I open others using:

```
var component = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/touch/content/SettingsMain.qml");
win = component.createObject(rootWindow2);
```

In main form I created object Network (it is C++ class)

```
Network{
        id: net1
}
```

Object "net1" is accesible by other QML objects which were not invoked by above code creating component. Unfortunately, all QML objects created by using the code above do not see "net1".I need something like global object for all QML files. Any ideas?

Comment: I would like to politely encourage the downvoter to give a comment to help the author understand the reason and provide guidance for the future, especially since the author appears to be relatively new here

Answer (score 1):

You should use a singleton for that, it exists for that exact purpose:

```
// in main.cpp
qmlRegisterSingletonType(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/touch/content/SettingsMain.qml")), "Core", 1, 0, "Settings");
```

Then you can access that from every QML file by importing:

```
import Core 1.0
//.. and use it
Settings.someProperty
Settings.someFoo()
```

You would also have to add a `pragma Singleton` line in the beginning of `SettingsMain`.

You can also skip registering the singleton from C++ if you implement a `qmldir` file, but IMO registering in C++ is better when the singleton is an integral part of the application.

When using qml singletons, you don't need to create the instance yourself, it will be automatically created.

Your question is ambigious as to what you actually want to be "global", I assume settings is one thing you would like to be global.

You can also register C++ objects as singletons in QML, for example:

```
qmlRegisterSingletonType<Network>("Core", 1, 0, "Network", someFooReturningValidNetworkPtr);
```

Comment: Your second approach is what I meant. However, now I get this issue when trying invoke function from Network.cpp:

qrc:/MainForm.qml:107 ((null)): qrc:/MainForm.qml:107: TypeError: Property 'findNewDevice' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: If you want to call functions from QML, make them `public slots:`

Comment: Well, it should work. Did you register it properly? `someFooReturningValidNetworkPtr` has to be the name of a function that returns a valid pointer to a `Network` object instance. `Network * foo() {...}`

Comment: I did not get error about NULL in this part of the code. Look:

[code] static QObject *manager_provider(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine)
{
    Q_UNUSED(engine)
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)
 Network* instance = Network::getInstance();
   return instance ;
}[code]

I think the problem is here:
Q_PROPERTY(int number  WRITE findNewDevice READ getDetectedDeviceCount)

Answer (score 1):

Singleton is not the only way. QML provides lots of ways to get same results.

Another way is to pass the `net1` id in as a property when calling `Qt.createObject()`. Example below:

### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Item {
        id: rootWindow2

        property Item settingsMain

        Network{
            id: net1
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            var component = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/touch/content/SettingsMain.qml");
            settingsMain = component.createObject(rootWindow2, {"net1": net1});
        }
    }
}
```

### SettingsMain.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {

    property Item net1

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("SettingsMain.qml: can I see net1? %1".arg(net1 ? "yes" : "no"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect :) Works well. Thanks

Comment: "Singleton is not the only way" - it is the only way for "global access" as the question is titled. Evidently, the OP doesn't actually need "global access". This approach is doable for simple scenarios, but it has disadvantages - it will be slow and inefficient for deep object trees, and the identifier can be shadowed at any level of the tree, thus cutting access. A singleton is not only the only way to get global access, it is also the most efficient and safest way to get access to exactly the object you want to.

Comment: To be fair, the singleton is cool. I didn't know it was possible to do for a QML component, and I agree the question has the wrong title